# Trying to combine the ParseName function and the Replace function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I put the below script together today.

```
SELECT ParseName(Replace([SrcID], '|', '.'), 1) As [F1],
ParseName(Replace([SrcID], '|', '.'), 2) As [F2],
ParseName(Replace([SrcID], '|', '.'), 3) As [F3],
ParseName(Replace([SrcID], '|', '.'), 4) As [F4],
ParseName(Replace([SrcID], '|', '.'), 5) As [F5],
ParseName(Replace([SrcID], '|', '.'), 6) As [F6],
ParseName(Replace([SrcID], '|', '.'), 7) As [F7]
FROM [tbl_Raw_History]
```

At first I thought it was working, but now I can tell it is doing something that I don't fully understand.  I can have up to 7 pipe characters in a string.  For some reason, after the 4th pipe is found, it stops working, and returns only NULL.

I know it's not working for sure, because I have around 5k records that follow this pattern:

```
TPOS|01|0|USD|I|SECU|US0642K|Jul 31 2017 12:00AM
```

None of these are returned in the query.  I want to parse the table on all 7 pipes, and combine this along with data from the original table.  So, I want the field named 'SrcID', as well as other fields named 'Position', 'TheDate', and several other fields as well.  How can I do that?  I am on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: PARSENAME is designed to parse ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName, not 7 values. That's why it craps out after 4. For splitting a string based on a certain delimiter, there are lots of answers out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't already have one, there are MANY "splitstring" functions freely available do what is needed here.

But if you want a specific, brute force approach, this may do the job. Test it on a larger sample though.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f8a2/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_Raw_History
    ( ID int identity(1,1) primary key,
      [SrcID] varchar(80))
;

INSERT INTO tbl_Raw_History
    ([SrcID])
VALUES
    ('TPOS|01|0|USD|I|SECU|US0642K|Jul 31 2017 12:00AM')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
*
from tbl_Raw_History
cross apply (
  select
     charindex('|',SrcID) 
   , charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID)+1)
   , charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID)+1)+1)
   , charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID)+1)+1)+1)
   , charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID)+1)+1)+1)+1)
   , charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
   , charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID,charindex('|',SrcID)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)
) p (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7)
cross apply (
  select
      substring(SrcID,1,p1-1)
    , substring(SrcID,p1+1,p2-p1-1)
    , substring(SrcID,p2+1,p3-p2-1)
    , substring(SrcID,p3+1,p4-p3-1)
    , substring(SrcID,p4+1,p5-p4-1)
    , substring(SrcID,p5+1,p6-p5-1)
    , substring(SrcID,p6+1,p7-p6-1)
    , substring(SrcID,p7+1,len(SrcID))
  ) s (s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2f8a2/1/0)**:

```
| ID |                                            SrcID | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4 | p5 | p6 | p7 |   s1 | s2 | s3 |  s4 | s5 |   s6 |      s7 |                  s8 |
|----|--------------------------------------------------|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|------|----|----|-----|----|------|---------|---------------------|
|  1 | TPOS|01|0|USD|I|SECU|US0642K|Jul 31 2017 12:00AM |  5 |  8 | 10 | 14 | 16 | 21 | 29 | TPOS | 01 |  0 | USD |  I | SECU | US0642K | Jul 31 2017 12:00AM |
```

**NB**: The column aliases p1...p7 of the first cross apply can be accessed as if column names in the second cross apply.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I just tried your sample and it worked excellent.  I will try the same on my actual data set when I get into my office tomorrow!!